# To have bibliography of Revtex along the text in two-columns

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, revtex

I am thinking about having a heading for **References**, since I think it is needed in publications.

My minimum tex

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}
\section{Methods}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida tellus sit amet eros varius, in blandit nibh vehicula. Vestibulum vel augue vitae erat posuere consequat. Cras nec suscipit dui. Sed laoreet tristique libero, quis consectetur leo tincidunt ut. Donec sodales rutrum est, at tempor eros laoreet eu. Aliquam vitae purus vel velit adipiscing dictum at nec turpis. Sed egestas feugiat eros, vel lacinia elit. Cras hendrerit erat vel suscipit adipiscing. Maecenas sed enim lacus. Aliquam suscipit dolor faucibus ornare elementum. Nam pretium, orci ac sagittis varius, odio est rutrum leo, sed adipiscing enim turpis vel lorem. Integer porttitor rutrum luctus. Duis vestibulum massa ante, non luctus enim tempor quis. Praesent condimentum fringilla fringilla. Nam eget sodales est, ultricies ullamcorper purus.

Nullam nisl erat, luctus nec libero et, faucibus suscipit massa. Suspendisse rhoncus laoreet ipsum eget posuere. Vivamus bibendum, dui vitae rhoncus sollicitudin, justo elit convallis felis, eget auctor nisi tellus non urna. Fusce semper ullamcorper sem. Nam enim enim, malesuada nec justo eget, pulvinar elementum purus. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque interdum ac diam tristique iaculis. Sed iaculis nisi vitae ipsum varius laoreet. Maecenas volutpat placerat facilisis. Sed eget arcu scelerisque, aliquet mauris nec, euismod ante. Nunc turpis velit, luctus et enim ut, lobortis scelerisque sapien. Cras ut aliquam dolor. Sed ac arcu eros. Nulla luctus egestas tincidunt. In eget quam dolor. Duis ut enim et justo vulputate tempor.

Etiam semper, justo sit amet elementum lacinia, enim lacus tincidunt lacus, eu pretium nulla arcu id nunc. Curabitur consequat tortor quam, vitae aliquam arcu tempor facilisis. Nam vehicula, mi et iaculis pulvinar, urna felis feugiat mi, eu tincidunt ante magna ac risus. Suspendisse id euismod velit. Nam in neque viverra lectus imperdiet mattis. Maecenas sapien erat, volutpat at feugiat ac, rhoncus tristique nunc. Sed sem dolor, blandit eu eleifend nec, rutrum at elit. Sed at metus eu sem blandit sollicitudin. Ut fermentum elit non ligula fermentum consequat. Maecenas pretium non lectus et tristique. Nunc suscipit, mi et placerat rutrum, nunc nisi rutrum massa, in malesuada leo massa non urna. Proin vulputate nunc a eleifend porta. Curabitur sit amet elit non est dictum pulvinar id id nunc. Cras ornare elit eget diam aliquam, in sagittis magna cursus.

Integer quis diam placerat, bibendum dui a, luctus ligula. Sed sit amet dolor vitae nulla pellentesque rhoncus. Nulla molestie purus vitae pharetra gravida. Nunc convallis hendrerit augue vel aliquet. Pellentesque ullamcorper diam enim, in condimentum nulla tincidunt in. Cras ac justo ac felis dictum ornare. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent vitae lorem varius, tincidunt ligula et, blandit nisl. Morbi posuere blandit elit sit amet porta. Sed ligula est, eleifend vel tempus a, dignissim at nunc. Sed fermentum nisi vel massa faucibus, ac pharetra turpis viverra. Nulla sit amet dolor rutrum, porta enim et, egestas justo. Maecenas eget varius turpis, eu placerat dui. Maecenas sit amet mollis nunc, quis volutpat orci.

\cite{berlin}


\section{References}
% if your bibliography is in bibtex format, use those commands:
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{article}      % Bibliography file (usually '*.bib' )

\end{document}
```

My bibtex

```
%  article.bib
% 
%  An example of bibtex entries.
%  Entries taken from BMC instructions for authors page.


% Article within a journal supplement
@ARTICLE{berlin,
    author  = {Radon P, Steinhoff U, von Wagner G, Kraft N}, 
    title   = {Quality evaluation of a pediatric ECG database for assessment of arrythmia detection algorithms in Automated External Defibrillators},
    journal = {Biomed Tech}, 
    year    = {2012},
    volume  = {57 (Suppl. 1)},
    issue = {Suppl. 1}

}
```

My output in print

[image]

**How can you have the bibliography follow the main text?**

Comment: Untestet: Can you try the document class option `nofootinbib`?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel The document class was not supported by my OSX LaTeX package and its extensions.

Comment: @Masi the option is part of revtex4-1 it is nothing to do with OSX or which LaTeX distribution you have.

Comment: Do you want to submit the paper to an APS journal? Then it doesn't make sense to tweak the layout. Better add the journal shortcut as a class option, e.g. `\documentclass[prl]{revtex4-1}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer is in Alex's comment. Use the code instead

```
documentclass[prl]{revtex4-1}
```