# Setting the bibliography RevteX along the text while keeping the number in sections

Tags: bibliographies, sectioning, citing, columns, revtex

I have this code for my Latex, using revtex 4 :

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext \cite{REF}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem[Citation]{REF}
Somebody.
\newblock Some title
\newblock \textup{Some Journal}. \textbf{0}\penalty0 (0):\penalty0 0--1 (2021).
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The result is :
[image]

But I would like the bibliography not to start in a new set of column, but rather on the same column as the text.

Following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139683/to-have-bibliography-of-revtex-along-the-text-in-two-columns?rq=1) if I change to : `\documentclass[prl,twocolumn]{revtex4}`, this is fixed, but a new problem appears that I lose the numbers in the section.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possibility, copying the corresponding piece of code from `aps4-2.rtx`. There might be better ways but I've never really got the hang of RevTeX's management of different journal styles.

Note that `revtex` is 20 years old and shouldn't be used for anything new; the current version is `revtex4-2`.

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% code taken from aps4-2.rtx
\makeatletter
\def\bibsection{%
   \par
   \begingroup
    \baselineskip26\p@
    \bib@device{\hsize}{72\p@}%
   \endgroup
   \nobreak\@nobreaktrue
   \addvspace{19\p@}%
  }%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext \cite{REF}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem[Citation]{REF}
Somebody.
\newblock Some title
\newblock \textup{Some Journal}. \textbf{0}\penalty0 (0):\penalty0 0--1 (2021).
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]